# .isBlank() Not Recognized in Java NetBeans

Tags: java, swing

I tried implementing .isBlank() to omit whitespace. The netBeans IDE 11.0 (and 8.2) shows "cannot find symbol" error.

When this project is opened from another PC it works!

```
public FormulaElement parseFormula(String text) {

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(text, "+-*/^√()!πe% \t", true);

        Vector<Object> vec = new Vector<>();
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        String temp= tokenizer.nextToken();
        //omitting whitespace
        if(temp.isBlank() == true){
           continue;
        }
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Which Java version are you using? `isBlank()` is available on `String` only in java 11+

Comment: when I run Java -version on CMD it shows,
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: So you have your answer.

Comment: With java 8, You can use like temp==null || temp.isEmpty(). Another way temp==null || temp.length()=0

Comment: @prasingh rather `temp==null || temp.trim().isEmpty()` (if you don't `trim`, it will return `false` if the string contains blanks)

Comment: @ernest_k good catch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To collect all the comments and putting some additional information. Here we are:

**JDK 11**

String class have isBlank() for checking blank string.

**Less then JDK 11**

There is no built in function. We have to tackle it is different way.

1. First check whether the string is `null`
2. If it is not `null` then Trim the string and check its length

Example:

1. `temp == null || temp.trim().length() == 0`
2. or, `temp == null || temp.trim().isEmpty()`. Note: is empty is internally checking length

Apart from this, there are some 3rd party Libs available that do this for us Like,

**Apache common lang**

It has various method for String. For our case `StringUtils.isBlank` is suitable candidate. I recommend you to read other string related methods too.

**Guava**

This lib also provide methods for string.

Example: `Strings.isNullOrEmpty()`